# Changing background of TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, background, tabcontrol, visual-tree

I would like to change the background color of a WPF TabControl:
[image]

Changing the background color of the TabControl does not work, because the Grid element (direct child of the TabControl) doesn't inherit the backround of its parent:
[image]

The code below works, but it changes the background color of all subsequent grids:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</TabControl>
```

Is there a more appropriate solution?

Comment: You'll need to "override" the TabControl default ControlTemplate and change the TabPanel Background. About the TabItem background, according to the default ControlTemplate it uses a gradient from ControlLightColor to ControlMediumColor. Redeclare them with the color you want to change TabItem's background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing answer, [nkoniishvt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418056/changing-background-of-tabcontrol#comment62342792_37418056) has already given right idea in comments, but I anyway will finish posting complete example.

1. Add `xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` namespace in your control.
2. Add this `ControlTemplate` in your `ResourceDictionary` in xaml:

   ```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomTabControlTemplate"  TargetType="TabControl" >
       <Grid ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" >
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Name="ColumnDefinition0" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="0" Name="ColumnDefinition1" />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="RowDefinition0" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" Name="RowDefinition1" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True" Name="HeaderPanel" Margin="2,2,2,0" Panel.ZIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Aqua" />
           <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="ContentPanel" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
               <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding TabControl.SelectedContent}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TabControl.SelectedContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding TabControl.SelectedContentStringFormat}" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
           </Border>
       </Grid>
       <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="TabControl.TabStripPlacement">
               <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>1</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>0</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <Thickness>2,0,2,2</Thickness>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Trigger.Value>
                   <x:Static Member="Dock.Bottom" />
               </Trigger.Value>
           </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="TabControl.TabStripPlacement">
               <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>0</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>0</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>0</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>1</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>0</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <Thickness>2,2,0,2</Thickness>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Trigger.Value>
                   <x:Static Member="Dock.Left" />
               </Trigger.Value>
           </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="TabControl.TabStripPlacement">
               <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>0</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>0</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>1</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <s:Int32>0</s:Int32>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="RowDefinition.Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <GridLength>0</GridLength>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <Thickness>0,2,2,2</Thickness>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Trigger.Value>
                   <x:Static Member="Dock.Right" />
               </Trigger.Value>
           </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
               <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Trigger.Value>
                   <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
               </Trigger.Value>
           </Trigger>
       </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   </ControlTemplate>
   ```

For example I set `Background="Aqua"` for `TabPanel` element inside root `Grid`.

3. Assign this `ControlTemplate` to the `Template` property of TabControl:

   ```
   <TabControl Template="{StaticResource CustomTabControlTemplate}">
       ...
   </TabControl>
   ```